# Keycloak Theme gives internal server error when trying to access reset password page

Tags: keycloak

I am customizing some login pages for keycloak with given [templates](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/main/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login)

Currently I am using the login template and registration template.


When I enable the reset password feature in the realms settings without adding the reset password template, I get no error when visiting said page but when I add the template [login-reset-password.ftl](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login/login-reset-password.ftl) I get an internal server error.


I added the template in the same folder as the other templates which are working if that helps

```
keycloak-clarity-theme
| - clarity/login
| - resources
| | - css
| | - img
| - login-reset-password.ftl
| - login.ftl
| - register.ftl
| - theme.properties
```

The error code:

```
GET http://localhost:10000/auth/realms/master/login-actions/reset-credentials?client_id=security-admin-console&tab_id=ZQYZbJJw3SY 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. I added the error code and updated the project structure. Unfortunately I can't show any code for security reasons.
So far I only added these 3 templates from the [repository](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/main/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login). Am I missing a key template to use the login-reset-password.ftl?